# show that $f'(x)$ is a Lebesgue measurable function.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lebesgue-measure

If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, show that $f'(x)$ is a Lebesgue measurable function.

My solution :

Define a sequence functions

$$ g_n = \frac {f(x + {\frac{1}{n})}-f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Then $f$ is measurable

$g_n$ is measurable for $\forall n$

then how to show that $f'(x)$ is a Lebesgue measurable function?

Comment: I wonder, why did you define $g_n$ in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Remember that if $\{f_n:A\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*}$ is a sequence of measurable functions then $\limsup f_n(x)$ and $\liminf f_n(x)$ are measurable functions.

Since $\lim g_n(x)$ exists and it’s equal to $f’(x)$ then you have $$\liminf g_n(x)=\limsup g_n(x)=f’(x),$$ therefore $f’$ is measurable.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: 
The limit of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable.